# No puedo insertar registros a la base de datos con PDO

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli, pdo

**Hola chic@s.** Tengo un problema al utilizar la clase de php PDO, ya que no me deja insertar registros a la base de datos. Ya lo probé con otras funciones como mysqli(tanto la versión procedural como la orientada a objetos) y funciona perfectamente, la conexión, la inserción, todo. Pero cuando lo pruebo implementando PDO, simplemente no funciona.

Aquí está la clase:

```
class ConnectionPDO{
        private $host = "localhost";
        private $user = "root";
        private $password = "";
        private $db_name = "TestData";
        private $unix_socket = "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock";
        public $connect;

        public function  __construct(){
            $conn_str = "mysql:unix_socket={$this->unix_socket};host={$this->host}; dbname={$this->db_name}; charset=UTF8;";
            try{
                $this->connect = new PDO($conn_str, $this->user, $this->password);
                $this->connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                echo "Connection okey :)";
            } catch(PDOException $err){
                die("Error: " . $err->getMessage());
            } 
        }

        public function insert($email, $user_name, $password){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO Users (email, user_name, password) VALUES (:email,:user_name,:password)";
            $query = $this->connect->prepare($sql);

            $query->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->execute();
        }
    }
```

Y este es el php del archivo principal:

```
include "connectPDO.php";
$connection = new ConnectionPDO();
if($_POST['submit_btn']){ //Boton que envia el formulario
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    //Connect
    $connection->insert($email, $user_name, $password);
}
```

**Muchas gracias ;)**

Comment: ¿Qué significa exactamente *no funciona*? Dinos si da error, una vez hayas corregido el método, pues es con `g`, algo así: `$err->getMesssage()` Aparte de eso, en el método `insert()` no tienes ningún control de nada ni devuelves nada para saber lo que ha ocurrido. Deberías controlar los posibles fallos y devolver información que indique al usuario que resultado tuvo la llamada a ese método.